# What does the apply javascript function do and when to use it?

Tags: javascript, apply

Can someone please explain how the apply javascript functions works? I thought I understood it but then this example below made me confused. Can someone explain in detail what the apply function is doing and WHY the answer is -1. What purpose does the `add` function passed in the apply function serve?

```
function add(x,y) {
   alert(x+y);
}

function subtract(x,y) {
   alert(x-y);
}

subtract.apply(add,[1,2]); //Return -1
```

Comment: console.log(x,y, x-y)

Comment: Best explanation I found useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain in detail what the apply function is doing

It calls a function, overriding the normal value of `this`, and lets you pass the arguments as an array.

> WHY the answer is -1.

The arguments are `1` and `2`. The subtract function alerts `1-2`.

> What purpose does the add function passed in the apply function serve?

Since the `subtract` function doesn't use `this`: Nothing at all. It would make the code clearer to pass `null` as the first argument to `apply`. Passing `add` is just a red herring.

Comment: thanks. Can you please give me an example where the `add` function would be useful?

Comment: @user5694093 — No. It isn't useful IMO.